# HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type - SOAP Webservice

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I am trying to access a soap based webservice . The webservice seems to be updated to jax-ws implementaion from jax-rpc and i am getting the following error from code

*StepException[message=HTTPS transfer failed while trying to send filename=d:/software/file.xml Cause: HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type ]*

While through SoapUI the webservice works fine. Following is the response header

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 24 Jul 2014 01:16:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
```

Client code is using `Content Type: application/soap+xml` could this be the reason for the above issue?